# JSON encode in bash

Tags: json, bash

Is there a better alternative than doing:

```
echo "{\"error\": \"Must be executed using the user account 'admin'.\"}" >&2;
```

in bash scripts?

Answer (score 2):

You could try a here document:

```
cat <<EOT
{"error": "Must be executed using the user account 'admin'."}
EOT
```

This works unless you have a single line containing only `EOT` by itself in the text you wish to `cat`.  If that's a problem, you can select an alternate token, e.g.

```
cat <<FOO
EOT
FOO
```

Additionally, if you find that even the basic here documents are resulting in unwanted expansion, e.g.

```
cat <<EOT
foo$a
EOT
```

will try to expand `$a`, you can quote the here document token to stop that expansion:

```
cat <<'EOT'
foo$a
EOT
```